# List of equations with particular formating

Tags: equations, lists

How can I do something like this? I want my list to be aligned left and equal signs to be on one vertical line[image: some list]

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the [amsmath](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package. Do familiarize yourself with Section 3, "Displayed equations", of the package's user guide.  The `align` environment should be of particular relevance.

Comment: Are those really left aligned?  You would see a gap in the first equations before the = signs if they were.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't find that display particularly attractive, but the source should be pretty much like the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\bar{y}_j^m(t)=
\Bigl(
  \bar{h}_j^m +
  \frac{t}{1!}\bar{h}_j^{m-1} +
  \frac{t^2}{2!}\bar{h}_j^{m-2} +
  \dots +
  \frac{t^q}{q!}\bar{h}_j^{m-q} +
  \dotsb
\\
  \dots +
  \frac{t^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\bar{h}_j^1
\Bigr)\exp\{\lambda t\},
\\
\vdots
\\
\bar{y}_j^{p_j}(t)=
\Bigl(
  \bar{h}_j^{p_j} +
  \frac{t}{1!}\bar{h}_j^{p_j-1} +
  \frac{t^2}{2!}\bar{h}_j^{p_j-2} +
  \dots +
  \frac{t^q}{q!}\bar{h}_j^{p_j-q} +
  \dotsb
\\
  \dots +
  \frac{t^{p_j-1}}{(p_j-1)!}\bar{h}_j^1
\Bigr)\exp\{\lambda t\},
\\
j=1,2,\dots,s.
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

The main difference is `\overline` in the original, rather than `\bar` (but the overbar is too big with the former).

[image]

A possible improvement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
&&\bar{y}_j^m(t)&=
\begin{aligned}[t]
\Bigl(
  \bar{h}_j^m +
  \frac{t}{1!}\bar{h}_j^{m-1} +
  \frac{t^2}{2!}\bar{h}_j^{m-2} +
  \dots +
  \frac{t^q}{q!}\bar{h}_j^{m-q} +
  \dotsb
\\
  \dots +
  \frac{t^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\bar{h}_j^1
\Bigr)\exp\{\lambda t\},
\end{aligned}
\\
&&&\;\;\vdots
\\
&&\bar{y}_j^{p_j}(t)&=
\begin{aligned}[t]
\Bigl(
  \bar{h}_j^{p_j} +
  \frac{t}{1!}\bar{h}_j^{p_j-1} +
  \frac{t^2}{2!}\bar{h}_j^{p_j-2} +
  \dots +
  \frac{t^q}{q!}\bar{h}_j^{p_j-q} +
  \dotsb
\\
  \dots +
  \frac{t^{p_j-1}}{(p_j-1)!}\bar{h}_j^1
\Bigr)\exp\{\lambda t\},
\end{aligned}
\\
\lefteqn{j=1,2,\dots,s.}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You were braver than me !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  amsmath package as suggested by Mico.
Here is a MWE that may suit your need, check the `\qquad` calls to obtain the right positionning of small lines, there may be a better way to do this.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
x &= x1 + \hdots + x2 + \hdots\\
&\qquad\qquad\hdots + x3, \\
&\qquad\qquad\vdots\\
x &= x1 + \hdots + x2 + \hdots,\\
&\qquad\qquad\hdots + x3, \\
\qquad & \qquad j = 1,\hdots,s.
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

`&` marks are used to align characters in separate lines.

[image: Result]